# How to get radiobutton with text on the same line?

Tags: css

Searched this place and tried the options suggested on different answeres, such as "display: block", float:left etc, but I cant manage to get them on the same line.

Here is the code the plugin have:

```
<div class="gift-certificate sc_info_box">
                                    <h3>Mottagare av presentkort</h3>
                                                                                    <div class="gift-certificate-show-form">
                                            <p>Vem vill du skicka ditt presentkort till?</p>
                                            <ul class="show_hide_list" style="list-style-type: none;">
                                                <li><input type="radio" id="hide_form" name="is_gift" value="no" checked="checked"> <label for="hide_form">Till mig!</label></li>
                                                <li>
                                                <input type="radio" id="show_form" name="is_gift" value="yes"> <label for="show_form">Till någon annan!</label>
                                                <ul class="single_multi_list" style="list-style-type: none;">
                                                <li><input type="radio" id="send_to_one" name="sc_send_to" value="one" checked="checked"> <label for="send_to_one">Send to one person</label>
                                                <input type="radio" id="send_to_many" name="sc_send_to" value="many"> <label for="send_to_many">Send to different people</label></li>
                                                </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                <div class="gift-certificate-receiver-detail-form">
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <div id="gift-certificate-receiver-form-multi">
                                                        <div class="form_table">
                        <div class="email_amount">
                            <div class="amount"><p class="coupon_amount_label"><span class="amount">1,500&nbsp;kr</span></p></div>
                            <div class="email"><input class="gift_receiver_email" type="text" placeholder="Email address..." name="gift_receiver_email[9216][]" value=""></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="message_row">
                            <div class="sc_message"><textarea placeholder="Message..." class="gift_receiver_message" name="gift_receiver_message[9216][]" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                        </div>
                <div id="gift-certificate-receiver-form-single">
                    <div class="form_table">
                        <div class="email_amount">
                            <div class="amount"><p class="coupon_amount_label"><span class="amount">1,500&nbsp;kr</span></p></div>
                            <div class="email"><input class="gift_receiver_email" type="text" placeholder="Mottagarens E-mail..." name="gift_receiver_email[0][0]" value=""></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="message_row">
                            <div class="message"><textarea placeholder="Ditt meddelande..." class="gift_receiver_message" name="gift_receiver_message[0][0]" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                                 
                </div></div>
```

This displays:
[image: This displays:]

So question is: How would I go about to get the text next to its button on the 2 rows? I need to work on mobiles aswell if possible.

Comment: You should post HTML code, not PHP code from which HTML code will be generated. You should ask separate questions separately, instead of adding an “extra question” that is not reflected in the title at all.

Comment: The code posted does not reproduce the problem. The problem is caused by something external to it (e.g. CSS settings) or excessively narrow width for the content involved.

Comment: Can you explain the nested ul tag? Can you also post any css?

Comment: I replaced it with the HTML code, does this help? Or do I need more of the code?

Comment: actually it is in line **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qZbUM/)** may you messed up with css already :D try to debug it with firebug or some like this. should be easy to finde

Comment: @Chiperific The nestled UL i think is for the option that follows if you click the buttons. I am not sure, It's a wordpressplugin I'm trying to make it work with my theme :/

Comment: Checkout http://getbootstrap.com for a css styling kit made by Twitter. It will make in-line and mobile scaling easy.

Comment: Hmm, very weird.. What you showed at that link @Dwza doesn't appear at my website.. The "send to one" or "send to more then one".. :S

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela is right, your code has no issues. Please post your CSS or indicate any stylesheets you are using. I'm still encouraging you to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) for your styling and mobile scaling options.

Comment: i just copied that what you posted. its just your plain html from your post :) just like i sayed... you have some in your css thats doing this wrong... or lets say not like you want. i also think that the "send" thing is just `display: none;` so check your css with your browser debug. what browser do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

Make your CSS:

```
li input[type="radio"], li label {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Their default layout is `display: block` which puts them on their own line regardless that you have placed them within one tag.